# Как в QuerySet вытащить объекты, которые были добавлены в модель за последние сутки

Tags: django, django-orm, queryset

Добрый день! Использую `Django 1.11`

Есть класс, который находится в `models.py`.
Назовем его **User**, в котором есть поле с названием **ID** для записи id пользователей.

Как я могу с помощью **QuerySet** вытащить всех пользователей с **поля ID** за последние сутки? 
Спасибо!

Comment: Можно создать в таблице дополнительную колонку "Created" типа datetime.

Comment: @Nikita а без этого никак?

Comment: Никак. Каким образом ORM должен узнать, когда какие записи созданы?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev понял) благодарю всех за ответы

Comment: Если Вы наследуете вашего User от [`django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) то у Вас уже имеются поля `id`, `last_login` и `date_joined`. _Возможно я неверно понял вопрос? Как вы определяете пользователя "за последние сутки"?_